# Вопросы по задаче, содержащей конструктор в java

Tags: java, конструктор

Добрый день!

**Дана задача:**
Провести три боя  попарно между котами

Создать три кота используя класс Cat.
Провести три боя попарно между котами.
Класс Cat создавать не надо.

Для боя использовать метод boolean fight(Cat anotherCat).
Результат каждого боя вывести на экран.

```
public class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Cat cat1 = new Cat("Petrovich", 30, 20, 16);
    Cat cat2 = new Cat("Vasiliych", 11, 12, 13);
    Cat cat3 = new Cat("Kuzyich", 13, 14, 15);


System.out.println(cat1.fight(cat2));
System.out.println(cat2.fight(cat3));
System.out.println(cat3.fight(cat1));
}

public static class Cat {

    public static int count = 0;
    public static int fightCount = 0;

    protected String name;
    protected int age;
    protected int weight;
    protected int strength;

    public Cat(String name, int age, int weight, int strength) {
        count++;                 //после каждого созданного кота количество увеличивается на 1

        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.strength = strength;
    }

    public boolean fight(Cat anotherCat) {
        fightCount++;   // после каждой драки количество драк увеличивается на 1

        int agePlus = this.age > anotherCat.age ? 1 : 0;         // если переменная класса, означающая возраст больше другого возраста кота, то выражение слева от двоеточия правильно, иначе второе
        int weightPlus = this.weight > anotherCat.weight ? 1 : 0;
        int strengthPlus = this.strength > anotherCat.strength ? 1 : 0;

        int score = agePlus + weightPlus + strengthPlus;
        return score > 2; // return score > 2 ? true : false;
    }
}
}
```

Возникли вопросы:

1.) Правильно ли я понимаю, что count++ увеличивает количество котов на 1 при создании нового объекта кота, то есть каждый раз когда я создаю кота, то срабатывает конструктор и также увеличивается количество котов в переменной count класса Cat, а при каждой драке также идет обращение к методу fight(Cat anotherCat), и параметр fightCount также увеличивается?

2.)  Не понимаю почему срабатывает метод public boolean fight(Cat anotherCat) когда вывожу на экран System.out.println(cat1.fight(cat2));

Не понимаю как метод понимает что this.age это cat1.age, а anotherCat.age - это cat2.age, и так далее, ведь это нигде напрямую не прописано.

Объясните пожалуйста если не трудно. Спасибо.

Comment: Подождите. Вы написали код, и теперь не знаете, что он делает?

Comment: @VladD Я примерно догадался, но не понял каким образом сравниваются значения при использовании метода fight, мне была дана изначально часть кода.

Comment: @VladD , что код делает я понимаю, но каким образом нет. =)

Comment: что то знакомое, JavaRush что ли?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Да, каждый раз когда будет вызываться конструктор Cat, count будет увеличиваться.И кол-во драк и при вызове метода так же будет увеличиваться.

2) Он выводит результат, потому что ты его вызываешь)

3) this - ключевое слово которые указывает на обьект, из которого был вызван.

Comment: то есть this. может также указывать не только на класс, но и на объект из которого был вызван, а в данном случае первый объект? а anotherCat - уже имя не важно, важно только то, что он второй?

Comment: @MaksimKorkodinov да, но чаще всего используется именно как указатель на объект из которого вызывали метод